# Timer Delay Not Working?

Tags: java, timer, bluej

I am trying to make this program print the current time in the console every second.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.Date;

public class E10U27 extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args){

   // Prep the listener to respond
   class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

         Date now = new Date();
         System.out.println(now);
      }
   }

   ActionListener listener = new TimerListener();
   final int DELAY = 1000; 
   Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, listener);
   t.start();    
}
}
```

However, it prints like 50 of just a single time (ex. 2:52 50 times), and so on.  It does tick correctly though.  How to make it run correctly? Are there any mistakes in my code?

Comment: if there are no mistakes, there is probably something wrong with bluej :/

Comment: How long did you wait? 1000 seconds is almost 17 minutes.

Comment: @FredK the OP complains that it doesn't wait at all

Comment: i changed delay to one, and it ticks correctly, but it prints out like 50 of each of them.

Comment: Your program seems to work fine (at least for delays short enough to catch on before Swing catches to the fact that there is no active window). So I've voted to close as "cannot repreduce". And the value `1` is one **millisecond**, not seconds. So you're bound to get lots of these.

Comment: before i edited my question, as before it seemed as if the delay was the same despite of the number.

Comment: that code is not complete, is it? It should do (almost) nothing since main is ended after starting the timer and there is no GUI visible. (other than this it should work perfectly)

Comment: how do i do it? Anything from after the main moved to before it will create errors.

Comment: but that is not the problem you have described - kind of confused now. To avoid the program to stop, add a `System.in.read()` at the end and eventually first printing out a nice message to "press RETURN to stop" - this will cause the main method to wait for an user input... but no idea how that works with BlueJ

Comment: im not asking for a user input nor wanting it to stop..

Comment: but I am suggesting you to ask for user input, so the program does not terminate, and I wrote nothing about "waiting it to stop"... probably to late to be up and I should stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the code without errors, but it finished without showing the date in the interval assigned to Timer, so I made some changes

1. Change the DELAY to 1000 (1 second) to print the current time every second

`final int DELAY = 1000;`

2. Create the frame to make the program keep running, otherwise the main method will finish `(new E10U27()).setVisible(true);`

This is the program with the modifications, it prints the current time every second:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.Date;

public class E10U27 extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        // Prep the listener to respond
        class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                Date now = new Date();
                System.out.println(now);
            }
        }

        ActionListener listener = new TimerListener();
        final int DELAY = 1000; // Milliseconds between timer ticks
        Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, listener);
        t.start();

        (new E10U27()).setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
final int DELAY = 999999;    
Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Your Action    
    }
    });
    timer.start();
```

Refer the document here [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)